# Knex Objection js Relationship not found Error

Tags: node.js, knex.js, objection.js

I am using Objection.js with Knex in a Node.js application and trying to pull data with a relationship. This has worked for me in the past, but on one of my tables it is saying the relationship does not exist:

`A model class DashboardLayout doesn't have relation component`

I have two tables, DashboardLayout and Component. DashboardLayout has a BelongsToOne relationship on Component. Here is how they are defined in the migration.

```
.createTable('components', table => {
    table.increments();
    table.string('name').notNullable();
    table.integer('componentTypeId').references('id').inTable('componentTypes');
    table.timestamps(true,true);
})
```

and

```
.createTable('dashboardLayouts', table => {
    table.increments();
    table.integer('x');
    table.integer('y');
    table.integer('w');
    table.integer('h');
    table.integer('dashboardId');
    table.integer('componentId').references('id').inTable('components');
    table.timestamps(true, true);
});
```

Then my DashboardLayout Model file looks like this:

```
const { Model } = require('objection');
const Component = require('./component');

class DashboardLayout extends Model {
    static get tableName() {
        return 'dashboardLayouts';
    }

    static relationMappings = {
        componentType: {
            relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
            modelClass: Component,
            join: {
                from: 'dashboardLayouts.componentId',
                to: 'components.id'
            }
        }
    }
}

module.exports = DashboardLayout;
```

But when I query the database with the following code it returns the error

`A model class DashboardLayout doesn't have relation component`

```
const layout = await DashboardLayout.query()
    .select(
        'dashboardLayouts.id',
        'dashboardLayouts.x',
        'dashboardLayouts.y',
        'dashboardLayouts.w',
        'dashboardLayouts.h',
        'dashboardLayouts.dashboardId',
        'dashboardLayouts.componentId'
    )
    .joinRelated({ component: true })
    .where('dashboardLayouts.dashboardId', '=', id);
return res.json(layout);
```

Maybe I have been looking at it for too long but I cannot see why the relationship is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because this line

```
.joinRelated({ component: true })
```

is using a different name than the defined in model

```
static relationMappings = {
    componentType: {
        relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
        modelClass: Component,
        join: {
            from: 'dashboardLayouts.componentId',
            to: 'components.id'
        }
    }
}
```

change it to `componentType`

Comment: I knew I was looking at this too long, I copied the model from one that had the ComponentType relationship. Thanks